# Drag scroll is not working in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In my application i have used fullcalendar for event scheduling. I can change event to same month by dragging it (which is in month view). But i want the event can be changed to next month while drag the event so that i have used

> dragScroll: true,

But its not working. Anyone please help me for this issue.

Below is my fullcalender coding

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        selectable: true,
        dragScroll: true,
        selectConstraint: {
            start: $.fullCalendar.moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
            end: $.fullCalendar.moment().startOf('month').add(1, 'month')
        },
        defaultView: 'month',            
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,basicDay,basicWeek'                              
        },
        timeFormat: 'H(:mm)t',
        buttonText: { 
            basicDay: 'List Day',
            basicWeek: 'List Week'
        },          
        allDayDefault: false,
        editable: true,

        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: data,
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
            element.click(function() {
                $("#startTime").html(moment(event.start).format('h:mm A'));
                $("#endTime").html(moment(event.end).format('h:mm A'));
                $("#eventInfo").html(event.title);
                $("#employee").html(event.employee);
                $("#date").html(moment(event.start).format('MMM Do'));
                $("#price").html(event.price);
                $("#duration").html(event.duration);
                $("#services").html(event.services);
                $("#eventLink").attr('href', 'appointments');
                //$("#services").dialog({ modal: true, title: event.title, width:350});
                $("#eventContent").modal();
            });
        },


        eventConstraint: {
            start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            end: '2100-01-01' // hard coded goodness unfortunately

            //start: moment('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            // start: '2000-01-01',
            // end: '2100-01-01' // hard coded goodness unfortunately
        },

        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc,date) {
                swal({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "To reschedule the "+ event.title +" appointment to "+event.start.format('MMM Do h:mm A'),
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                    confirmButtonText: "Reschedule",
                    closeOnConfirm: false,
                    closeOnCancel: false
                }, function(isConfirm){

                    if (isConfirm) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: 'reschedule',
                            data: {id:event.id,date:event.start.format()},
                            success: function (result) {
                                if(result==1)
                                {
                                    swal("Success!", "The appointment was rescheduled.", "success");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    swal("Failure!", "Failed to reschedule.", "warning");
                                    revertFunc();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        swal("Cancelled", "Appointment reschedule calcelled", "error");
                        revertFunc();
                    }
                });
        }

    });
```

Comment: "dragScroll" is working fine. It just doesn't do what you're hoping it does. What is _does_ do is cause the _current scroll container_ to be moved. This will come into force if your calendar is wider or taller than its container, causing scrollbars to appear. Then if you drag to the edge, it'll carry on scrolling over the _content that is already there_. What you're asking for is for it to _change the current fullCalendar view_, which would cause _different content_ to be displayed. The docs clearly say that's not what it does. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/dragScroll/

Comment: Like I told you 3 versions of this question ago, what you're asking for is a completely new feature and would involve far more implementation details than is suitable for an SO question. Quite possibly you'd even need to modify the source code. So you'll need to attempt this for yourself first, then ask a question if you're stuck.

Comment: As some sort of help, here are my suggestions for what you'd need to implement: You need to detect dragging of an event to the edge of the _calendar_ (_not_ the _container_, like dragScroll does, in case the calendar is larger than that) and then cause the view to be changed, as if the "next" or "previous" button was pressed. Then you'd have a dilemma whether to wait for the changed events to be loaded (async, of indeterminate time, remember), so you can detect overlaps, if that's necessary for you, before you allow the event to be dropped.

Comment: And if the user cancels the drop, or drops where they're not allowed to, or outside the calendar, you have to go back to the original view. And if you want to support selecting of new events as well, it gets even more complex because you have to remember the area selected on the view(s) (e.g. if it overlaps multiple weeks it could be multiple time periods to remember) that no longer exist, even though the user hasn't finished dragging yet, and might even decide to shorten the area so that it falls back into the previous screen. So you see, there's quite a lot to do...

Comment: ...and chances are I've probably forgotten something, that's just off the top of my head. Now do you believe me this is too broad for SO without you making an attempt yourself? We can help you fix something if you get stuck in a particular area. Of course if you feel this feature is too much work to do yourself, or you feel you haven't got the right expertise, you might be better to put in a request with the fullCalendar maintainer on GitHub, or even pay someone else to write the feature as an extension.